# Cannot load symbols in GlowCode x64

Tags: c++, profiling, native, glowcode

This question might be too application specific to be out here on SO, but here goes.

I am trying to profile a simple native c++ application using GlowCode-x64 6.2 .

The problem is that no matter which settings I set in the **"Options->Symbol server and search path"** the symbols are never loaded. My .pdb files are all in the same folder as the .exe file too.

When entering the **"Running->Hooks"** menu and adding modules I always get **"Not loaded"** in the "Address" column.

I have read the startup tutorial several times and followed it every step of the way.

I have even tried profiling the same program using AQTime6, which worked perfectly. So I know that the debug information is there.

I also recall using GlowCode 2 years ago on my 32bit laptop, and got it working at once.

Any help beyond "read the manual again" is greatly appreciated.

Edit:

Just wanted to point out that my application is built with the VS2005 SP1 compiler.

Edit2:

Just got home from work and tried GlowCode at home on Win32. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Do you have Debugging Tools for Windows installed?

Comment: Not sure. I haven't explicitly installed them.

Comment: I visited the GlowCode site and found that version 6.2 is only 32 bit build and not 64. GlowCode 7.0 has both the installers, 32 bit and 64 bit. This might be your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I visited the GlowCode site and found that version 6.2 is only 32 bit build and not 64. GlowCode 7.0 has both the installers, 32 bit and 64 bit. This might be your problem.

Comment: Might be, I posted this question so long ago that I can´t remember much about it. I did use  GlowCode-x64 though, which I kind of assumed was 64 bit.

Comment: No. I never solved the problem. I forgot about it. This happened 3 years ago.